# Does having a golem with its own challenge rating change your ECL?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-levels

I have a character that is a level 16 Psion Shaper. He has two iron golems with him at all time (Out of the ten he possesses altogether). He acquired them by first crafting the body himself, he then bought a golem manual and finally had a wizard activate the manual's spell trigger on his pre-made construct. Each iron golem has a challenge rating of 13; does this stack with my ECL? If it does how do you calculate the increase if I have more or less of them at one time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you bought them, each one’s CR is accounted for in the 15,000 gp you spent on the raw materials, the 375 days you spent making the body, the 35,000 gp you spent on the *iron golem manual*, and the 150 additional days spent bringing it to life. For two, double that. 100,000 gp and three years of work are rather substantial, after all. They have no effect on your ECL.

Comment: My character is a psion shaper and crafted the golems body himself. He then bought a golem manual and had a wizard activate the spell trigger. I found the golem manuals on D&D wiki on an SRD page but can't seem to find where they are in an actual book?

Comment: @Craigamore Those books are legit, I'll look for a page number when I get home. That's fine, that's just another way to buy them. No effect on CR or ECL.

Comment: @Craigamore You should probably add that information to the question, along with the class and level of your character. (That is, it makes little difference to a Wiz30 if he has a pair of iron golems, but it makes a huge difference to a Ftr2!)

Comment: Is the answer any different for an NPC?

Comment: @Roflo No, it’s not, assuming NPC wealth went towards a pair of *iron golem manuals*. If an NPC just has two iron golems with him because the DM says so, then their CR would be included.

Comment: Okay, I have gone over the math that you used in your answer and I don't understand how it works. The raw materials cost 10,000 gp for an iron golem and the manual does cost 35,000 gp. But I don't understand where the days of construction are coming from, mostly the 375?

Comment: @Craigamore I believe the body is 15,000? Anyway, I did assume you were just meeting the minimum DC 20 Craft check. To determine how long mundane crafting, that is, with the Craft skill rather than an Item-Creation feat, you divide the the price of the item in silver by the product of the DC and the check. Assuming a check of 20, that's 150,000/400, or 375. A higher check would reduce the time taken, and if it was high enough you could voluntarily increase the DC (in increments of 10) to reduce the time more.

Comment: Although now that I write that out, that progress is in weeks rather than days, I think. I will have to double-check that. Point is, mundane crafting takes a preposterously long time.

Comment: I should have thought of that, but if the crafting of the body is mundane then shouldn't I be able to use Greater Fabricate to craft the body in less than thirty seconds? I was more thinking that crafting the construct fell in under the feat of craft construct that the manual allows you to use for the creation of the body. After the body was created using the feat I would then have the wizard use the spell trigger to activate the book.

Comment: @Craigamore Yes, there are ways around it, and *greater psionic fabricate* appears to be one of them.

Comment: With mundane crafting, wouldn't the XP cost affect the ECL (ie, by losing some XP the character would be slightly behind its peers)? I don't see any XP cost mentioned in Fabricate though.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Mundane crafting doesn’t require XP; only magical crafting does. The *iron golem manual* covers that.